# auditd augenrules lost meaning

Tags: linux-audit

```
[root@rock:/var/log/audit] : service auditd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status auditd.service
  auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-01-11 08:24:35 EST; 51min ago
     Docs: man:auditd(8)
           https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation
  Process: 94529 ExecStartPost=/sbin/augenrules --load (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 94513 ExecStart=/sbin/auditd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 94515 (auditd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/auditd.service
           +-94515 /sbin/auditd
           +-94517 /sbin/audispd
           +-94519 /usr/sbin/sedispatch

Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: lost 4892
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: backlog 0
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: enabled 1
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: failure 1
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: pid 94515
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: rate_limit 0
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: backlog_limit 1048576
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: lost 4892
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock augenrules[94529]: backlog 0
Jan 11 08:24:35 rock systemd[1]: Started Security Auditing Service.
```

In RHEL 7.9 when using `auditd` I believe I have everything working well but when I do the above I see **lost 4892**

what does that lost value mean?  Is it bad?  Should I want that to be zero?

For reference below is my `/etc/audit/auditd.conf`

```
#
# This file controls the configuration of the audit daemon
#

local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_group = root
log_format = RAW

flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 100

# max log file size in MB, does not matter with KEEP_LOGS
max_log_file = 10000

max_log_file_action = KEEP_LOGS

# no log rotation
num_logs = 0
priority_boost = 0

admin_space_left_action = SINGLE
disk_full_action = SINGLE
disk_error_action = SINGLE

disp_qos = LOSSLESS
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = HOSTNAME

space_left = 500
admin_space_left = 300

space_left_action = email
verify_email = yes
action_mail_acct = root

use_libwrap = yes
##tcp_listen_port = 60
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
```

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here using audit, according to the man page of auditctl when using the -s option:

> -s     Report the kernel's audit subsystem status. It will tell you the in-kernel values that can be set by -e, -f, -r, and -b options.  The  pid  value  is  the
> process  number  of  the  audit  daemon.  Note that a pid of 0 indicates that the audit daemon is not running. **The lost entry will tell you how many event
> records that have been discarded due to the kernel audit queue overflowing**. The backlog field tells how many event records are  currently  queued  waiting
> for auditd to read them. This option can be followed by the -i to get a couple fields interpreted.

The part that talks about **lost** value is in bold.